# where does `resource://gre/res/html.css` come from?

Tags: css, firefox, firebug

I'm just using **ASP.NET MVC 2** and realized that I get a **ghost stylesheet**

[image]

And I can't get ride of it...

Biggest problem is that on other browser I do get the same behavior with this ghost CSS, and it's driving me crazy!

On the image above I'm using Firefox 3.6.11 with Firebug 1.5.4

I have this `html.css` file nowhere in my Visual Studio Solution, how can I get ride of it as it's screwing my design with it's **line 345**

```
ul, menu, dir {
    display:block;
    list-style-type:disc;
    margin-bottom:1em;
    margin-left:0;
    margin-right:0;
    margin-top:1em;
    padding-left-ltr-source:logical;
    padding-right-rtl-source:logical;
    padding-start-value:40px;
}
```

Comment: It is built in css coming from the browser

Answer (score 3):

`C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\res\html.css` is the location of the css.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, with Firefox v68, forms.css is located in :
    `"c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\omni.ja\chrome\toolkit\res\forms.css"`
where `omni.ja` is a ZIP archive.